# usage of physical and abstract bit of uvm_comparer uvm1.2

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In uvm1.2 library uvm_comparer.svh two filter bits has been added "physical" and "abstract". Could any one give me the proper usage of those filter bits.

Answer (score 0):

These are field attribute settings that came from Specman ->OVM -> UVM that control the policy classes like compare/pack/print, etc. It is left up to the user what you want to do with them. See https://accellera.mantishub.com/view.php?id=5409